# How can I so a "cascading" merge from an upstream branch and pass the merge to all downstream branches with one command?

Tags: git, merge

I got a "Parent" branch. Branch A is a branch of Parent, Branch B is a branch of Branch A and Branch C is a branch of Branch B:

```
------ Parent
  \----Branch A
     \------ Branch B
        \------- Branch C
```

I want to merge some changes into Branch A and then pass those same changes onto Branches B and C. Is there a way this can be done easily? Perhaps I can use the `--contains` mechanism which lists the contained branches and do this with bash? I googled for a solution like that but didn't find one.

Comment: There is nothing built into git that does this for you. Git does not track which branch is a parent of another branch, that concept does not exist in git, and git does not have any means available to deduce that information either. As such, git has no notion of "downstream" branches. They become apparent for you when you draw it out on a diagram, but that's because you already know how they are linked. However, that knowledge does not exist in the repository. You have no other option than to manually do the job. You can write a script that does it, but it will have to do one branch at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My usual approach is to rebase A onto its parent, then B onto A, and C onto B.

Unfortunately, Git won't do this for you. You could write a script using `git branch --contains` recursively.

Comment: Yeah, that's the direction I'm headed down. I'm going build it into post-merge hook.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've done it with a crude post-commit hook in git hub written in perl. My branch naming convention allows me to do this based on branch names. There are a couple of little tricks needed to get output from the `branch --list`, namely turning a paging setting off and back on in git.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# get the current branch name
my $curr_branch = `git branch --show`;
chomp $curr_branch;

# get the names of all the branches that have this branch as parent and merge commit into each of them
if ($curr_branch eq 'configs') {
    `git config --global pager.branch false`;
    my $out = `git branch --list --no-color --no-column`;
    `git config --global pager.branch true`;
    my @list = grep { /\scfg_/ } split /\n/, $out;
    foreach my $l ( @list ) {
        print "Merging to $l\n";
        `git checkout $l`;
        `git merge --no-edit configs`;
    }
}

`git checkout configs`;
```

I've symlinked the my unsued `post-merge` script to this `post-commit` script so it's also triggered on merges with another branch.